# what is best option to select database among two?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

i have two options to create database for my MVC application

1. via Built-in Sql express in visual studio (Linq to sql)
2. via Sql server 2010 and then connecting it with my MVC app.

i found option 1 more comfortable but what's the difference ? drawbacks of using 1 instead of 2 or reverse.

Answer (score 0):

if you use linq to sql then i think you can not modify your database where as via second option you can.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the visual studio uses is the express edition integrated by microsoft to help beginners. Features is difference... express edition has less features as compare other editions, read the following links

[First link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5222e667-c7f9-470b-9f55-d16b191f5f4d/difference-between-sql-server-editions)

[Second link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1275361.aspx)

major differnces are:

1. uses only 1 CPU
2. can use max of 1 GB of RAM
3. Automatic corruption recovery from mirror
4. Log stream compression
5. Backup compression
   and many more...

[SQL Server Editions Comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions.aspx)